# Problems with some angular-material components above angular-material-toolbar

Tags: angular, angular-material, toolbar

I need to use input, checkbox, and radio button, and I have a mat-toolbar at the top of my page. When I scroll down, all of these component go above the toolbar.

I tried to play with the z-index property for all of the components, but it don't work.

[image: My toolbar]

In red you can see my toolbar, and the radio and checkbox below. The labels are below as I need.

There you have a workspace for more details, but the problem is resolved 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w15mzv?embed=1

Comment: Do you mind to post code to demonstrate the issue? There could be many ways to write.

Comment: create code example on stackblitz or other similar tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay sorry, while I put some code on a stackblitz project to put it in (I can put the whole app, not allowed) I saw my error:
My toolbar was in a component, I put a z-index style on my toolbar inside my component.

While I'm puting my code on stackblitz, I don't had the problem so I try to put my z-ibdex on my component too and it work.

Thanks guys for your time and sorry for having waste it